# Best way to distribute queue uniquely across php processes

Tags: php, queue, rabbitmq

I have a set of unique values, and I want to give each request one of those.

Each value may only be distributed once. The order is not important. 
I'm looking for a good tool to do this.

I've been thinking about using MySQL with `SELECT .. LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE`. Works, is there a way to select an unlocked row instead of waiting for the first lock the release?

I have tried using rabbitmq, registering each request as a consumer consuming just one message, but this method is slow. Taking almost a second over WAN.

Comment: That's weird usually RMQ is quite fast. Maybe message size too big?

Comment: Message size is just a couple of bytes. RMQ is fast, but there seems to be quite some delay when connecting (high WAN latency). But even on a local network, it takes over 0.05 second to grab a message.

Comment: That's weird. When I ran the tests some time ago, I was processing about 5-6k msgs/s and they were 10-50KBs

Comment: Yeah; 1 consumer can handle lots of messages. The issue is I want thousands of consumers each second just handling one message each.

Comment: You mean like handle one message and then die, or one message at the time?

Comment: One message and die. I want to give each HTTP request a predefined unique identifier used in a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments

> there seems to be quite some delay when connecting [to RMQ]

yes, there definitely is! in some cases, i've seen the connection take 5 to 10 second or more.

but the way we are supposed to manage RabbitMQ is to have a single open connection per application instance - open it when the app instance starts, and leave it open forever.

when we need to do work, create a channel on which to do the work.

channels are cheap and very fast to open and close, unlike connections.

Comment: Good idea! Currently the php-amqplib which I'm using does not appear to support this. Will look into it to get this working. Do you think using RMQ is the best solution (over for ex. Redis lists)?